# Ng-options in bootstrap-select doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-select

I want to add multi select to my app, but when I try loading data from controller select doesn't work. I used ng-options and ng-repeat in select but both doesn't work. [My plugin: bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)

[My code in jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qizarumudi/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a jQuery plugin in AngularJS, you can use it by calling the function in a directive binded with the element as shown below:

**HTML:**

```
<select class="selectpicker" bootstrap-selectpicker data-ng-model="modelValue" multiple="" data-actions-box="true">
 <option>Mustard</option>
 <option>Ketchup</option>
 <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

**Directive:**

```
app.directive('bootstrapSelectpicker'), function(){
var bootDirective = {
    restrict : 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attr){
        $(element).selectpicker();
    }         
};
   return bootDirective;
});
```

But i would recommend using Angularjs based dropwdowns, take a look at following plugin.

http://isteven.github.io/angular-multi-select/#/main

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/

http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-bootstrap-multiselect
https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I work with `ng-repeat` on the `option` tag. For me running the following function each time I get new data does the job:

```
function selectPickerRefresh() {
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.$digest();
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
    });
}
```